# c++, static_cast <int> of float point calculation and possible of losing integers

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, static-cast

With the following code:

```
    int ten{ 1 };
    double zeroPnine{ 0.9 };

    cout << ten - zeroPnine << endl; // 0.1
    cout << (ten - zeroPnine) * 10 << endl; // 1
    cout << static_cast <int>(ten - zeroPnine) << endl; // 0    
    cout << static_cast <int>((ten - zeroPnine) * 10 )<< endl; // 1
```

I am expecting the last line to output 1, but actual output is in actually 0, how come?

Full output:
0.1
1
0
0

Comment: Because of the imprecisions of the floating point format on computers, which can cause rounding errors.

Comment: If you print out the last line without the static cast, it shows 1, or at least something close to 1. But if you say "((ten - zeroPnine) * 10) == 1", it says false for the reason Joachim states. The values are imprecise. Floating points should be relied upon for relative values, not discrete points.

Comment: `0.9` is not an integer by the way.

Comment: I understand 0.9 isn't integer, but 1 - 0.9 = 0.1, and 0.1 * 10 should give me 1, why is it a problem?

Comment: Due to how floating point numbers work, `0.9` is actually `0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625`

Comment: possible duplicate of [double precision C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016407/double-precision-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best advice would be to avoid using static_cast  to convert double.

Try converting double to int before doing the calculation if you want the answer to be integers.